# What is the probability that $B$ has at least one pair of elements whose sum is divisible by $15$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $A=\left\{0,5,10,15,...195\right\}$.Let $B$ be any subset of $A$ with at least $15$ elements. What is the probability that $B$ has atleast one pair of elements whose sum is divisible by $15$?

How should I attempt this question, which I could not start?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Notice that in the set A there are:

- $13$ numbers congruent to $5 \pmod {15}$
- $13$ numbers congruent to $-5 \pmod {15}$
- $14$ numbers congruent to $0 \pmod {15}$

Can you see where to go from here.....maybe think about the case when $B$ contains $0$,$1$ or strictly more than $1$ element congruent to $0 \pmod {15}$ and apply the pigeon hole principle. Hope this helps.